# Question on an algebraic inequality

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Let $a,b,c,d,x,y,z$ be real numbers such that 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
a+b+c+d=&0,\\
a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=&1,\\
x+y+z=&0,\\
-1\leq x,y,z\leq& 2.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Is it possible to show that
\begin{equation*}
2-[x(ab+cd)+y(ac+bd)+z(ad+bc)]\geq 0\ ?
\end{equation*}

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Without loss of generality, you can go ahead and set $d$ and $z$ to $1$, and see if that makes the inequality easier to prove.

Comment: @DavidH Except you would lose generality?  All of $a,b,c,d$ or $x,y,z$ or both, could be zero?  That, and the second term isn't symmetric in permutations of the variables?

Comment: I modified the question according to your suggestions, thanks!

Comment: Where is the problem from? Or what it the reason for the inequality? Or where did it come from?

Comment: it is related to optimization for matrices, in fact, -1, -1, 2 are eigenvalues of a matrix, and x, y, z are diagonal entries.

Comment: @John There has to be at least one non-zero parameter in both groups for the problem to be non-trivial. I was operating under the assumption that the OP had already figured that much out. ;) Also, the permutation asymmetry is irrelevant. Since the relations are scale invariant, we're free to let one of the non-zero parameters set the scale.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=ab+cd,  B=ac+bd,  C=ad+bc$
then
$$(a+b+c+d)^2=0$$
$$\iff 2A+2B+2C=-1$$
If $x,y,z\leq2$, then
$$xA+yB+zC\leq2A+2B+2C=-1<2$$

Comment: $(a+b+c+d)^2=0 \iff (a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)+2ab+2cd+2ac+2bd+2ad+2bc=0 $. Thus $1+2A+2B+2C=0$

Comment: @BeaumontTaz: just modified!

Comment: @bleish Actually, I feel a little uneasy about the first inequality on the last line. Looking at a simpler inequality: $xA\le 2A$ if $x\le2$. This fails for $A<0$. I don't know if having $B,C$ and their relationship to $A$ or $y,z$ and their relationship to $x$ changes that. But it seems a little off to me.

Comment: Consider $a=c=-1/2,b=d=1/2,x=z=-1,y=2$. These satisfy all of the requirements. $A=-1/2,B=1/2,C=-1/2$ and $xA+yB+zC=1/2+1+1/2=2$ and $2A+2B+2C=-1$. Clearly, $2 > -1$ and therefore, this inequality doesn't work. However, I want to make sure to note that this isn't a counterexample for the inequality in the question. Equality actually holds for these numbers for the question. This is only a counterexample for the inequality in the last line of this answer.

Comment: @BeaumontTaz: you're right!